# How to replace characters or words in a string using javascript even with no space between them?

Tags: javascript

I have a function something like this :

```
 var exchange = function(code) {
     var ref = {
       'one' : '1' , 
       'two' : '2' ,
       'three' : '3'
     }; 
   return code.split(' ').map( function (a) { 
     return a.split(' ').map( function (b) { 
        return ref[b]; 
     }).join(''); 
   }).join(' '); 
 };
```

So now I do it :

```
 var strg = "one two three";
 alert( exchange( strg ) ); // => 123
```

It works fine but I have a problem. Let me explain. I want it to execute same as now till with no space between.

For example :

```
 var strg = "onetwothree";
 alert( exchange( strg ) ); // => Nothing
```

But I want it to change the text even with no spaces. How can I do that ?

Comment: The problem with no space is that you'll have to do a direct replace (rather than your split on white space) which then could replace tone with t1.

Comment: Please add more details with some examples

Comment: To get it without space you'd need to start looking for the keys in the string without requiring them to be complete words (i.e. requiring white space), thus words containing any of the keys would have part replaced. An example from my first comment: tone with t1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a regular expression with a joined string with pipe and replace found string with the values.

```js
var exchange = function(code) {
        var ref = { one: '1',  two: '2', three: '3' }; 
        return code.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(ref).join('|'), 'ig'), k => ref[k]);
    };

console.log(exchange("onetwothree"));
```

Comment: This is the exact solution I was referring to in my comment. Run this code with "tone" instead of "onetwothree" and it'll result in "t1".

Comment: I got it !! Thanks for your guidance

Comment: right, that is a problem of not having separators. i think op knows this.

Comment: maybe a sorted object would help, where longer strings come first and shorter at the end to get the longer string replaced first, depending on the content.

Comment: Oh I understood !!

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over number values and replace them.

```
 var exchange = function(code) {
     var ref = {
       'one' : '1' , 
       'two' : '2' ,
       'three' : '3'
     }; 
   Object.keys(ref).forEach(k => code = code.replace(k, ref[k]))
  return code
 };
 var strg = "onetwothree";
 alert( exchange( strg ) ); // => 123
```

Answer (score 2):

I think likely the best thing to do is to create a standard parser constructor that goes character by character and then provide it a configuration and a function wrapper.

**Constructor**

```
//Parsing input output constructor;
function ParseFor( i, o ) {
    this.str = i;
    this.indexLength = this.str.length - 1;
    this.arr = [ ...i ];
    this.pointer = 0;
    this.output = o;
    this.match = false;
    this.reset = function() {
        this.pointer = 0;
        this.match = false;
    }
    this.next = function( c ) {
        if ( this.arr[ this.pointer ] === c ) {
            if ( this.pointer === this.indexLength ) {
                this.match = true;
            } else {
                this.pointer++;
            }
        } else {
            this.reset();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Parse Work with RegEx and Constructor**

```
    let parsers = [];
    for ( let [ k, v ] of Object.entries( ref ) ) parsers.push( new ParseFor( k, v ) );
    let parsedStr = str.replace( /./g, ( c ) => {
        let output = "";
        parsers = parsers.map( parser => parser.next( c ) );
        parsers.forEach( parser => {
            if ( parser.match ) {
                parser.reset();
                output = parser.output;
            }
        } );
        return output;
    } );
```

**Parse Function Wrapper**

```
function parseStr( str, ref ) {

//... PARSE CONSTRUCTOR

//... PARSE WORK
    return parsedStr;
}

parseStr( "onetwothree",  {
        'one': '1',
        'two': '2',
        'three': '3'
    });
```

---

### EXAMPLE:

```js
function parseStr( str, ref ) {

//Parsing input output constructor;
function ParseFor( i, o ) {
 this.str = i;
 this.indexLength = this.str.length - 1;
 this.arr = [ ...i ];
 this.pointer = 0;
 this.output = o;
 this.match = false;
 this.reset = function() {
  this.pointer = 0;
  this.match = false;
 }
 this.next = function( c ) {
  if ( this.arr[ this.pointer ] === c ) {
   if ( this.pointer === this.indexLength ) {
    this.match = true;
   } else {
    this.pointer++;
   }
  } else {
   this.reset();
  }
  return this;
 }
}

//parse work

 let parsers = [];
 for ( let [ k, v ] of Object.entries( ref ) ) parsers.push( new ParseFor( k, v ) );
 let parsedStr = str.replace( /./g, ( c ) => {
  let output = "";
  parsers = parsers.map( parser => parser.next( c ) );
  parsers.forEach( parser => {
   if ( parser.match ) {
    parser.reset();
    output = parser.output;
   }
  } );
  return output;
 } );
 return parsedStr;
}

console.log( parseStr( "onetwothree",  {
  'one': '1',
  'two': '2',
  'three': '3'
 }) );
```